# jQuery Draggable/Droppable animate remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm running into an issue when I try to call `remove()` after an animation on a draggable element.

Basically, when an element is dropped, I want to:

1. Animate the scale of the dropped element down
2. Remove the element, so that another element can be dragged, if needed

Right now what happens is:

1. The scale animation works
2. The remove() call does not remove the element's placeholder, which then prevents the user from dragging any other elements

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
   ui.draggable.effect("scale", {
     scale: "content",
     percent: 1
   }, 100, function() {
     return ui.draggable.remove();
   });
});
```

The same issue seems to appear when you do a `setTimeout` function around the `ui.draggable.remove();` call, so it's got to be some kind of timing issue.

Has anybody has come across this problem before? A nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated!